# Angular access component property in custom pipe

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular-pipe

I currently have a simple search function implemented [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-course-filter-pipe-mbb53i?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhighlight-filter.pipe.ts) that allows a user to search for courses. Currently only the live `searchText` from the user input is highlighted using the highlight pipe:

```
<td> <div [innerHTML]= "course.course_title | highlight : searchText"></div> 
<td>  
 <read-more [text]="course?.description | highlight : searchText" [maxLength]="75"> </read-more>
 </td>
  <td>  
    <read-more [text]="course?.keywords | highlight : searchText" [maxLength]="50"> </read-more>
 </td>
```

The highlighting is done with the following regex:

```
transform(value: string, args: string): any {

if (args && value){
   var re_noSpace = /\s*,\s*/;
   var queryList = args.split(re_noSpace).filter(String);
   var re_matchQueries = new RegExp(queryList.join('|'),"gi");
   //e.g. if args was linear,equa, the regExpr will become  /linear|equa/gi
   return value.replace(re_matchQueries,(x)=>"<mark>"+x+"</mark>");
}
```

The user can filter courses using commas (`linear algebra, data science`) or by adding them through the button.  As the user adds filters to the `searchTerms` array through the button, I would like to highlight *both* the current `searchText` as well as all previous search terms.

Test case: if a user adds `linear algebra` and `data science` as filters through the buttons, the live highlighting should still occur as the user is typing, with the addition that any previous terms are also highlighted so the user can see where previous terms have matched.

My idea is to adjust the highlight pipe with the inclusion of the previous searchTerms in the regex (`includePreviousTerms`):

```
transform(value: string, args: string): any {

if (args && value){
   var re_noSpace = /\s*,\s*/;
   var queryList = args.split(re_noSpace).filter(String);

   var includePreviousTerms = queryList.concat(this.searchTerms); 

   var re_matchQueries = new RegExp(includePreviousTerms.join('|'),"gi");
   return value.replace(re_matchQueries,(x)=>"<mark>"+x+"</mark>");
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to access `this.searchTerms` from the pipe since I can't import it.  I might be able to access the array by passing it from the view:

```
 <td> <div [innerHTML]= "course.course_title | highlight : searchTerms"></div> 
 <td>  
     <div [innerHTML]="course.description | highlight : searchTerms">  </div>
</td>
```

But then I would no longer get the live highlighting.  How can I implement this approach or what would be a better way to reconcile the two?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an extra parameter to your pipe, like so:

```
transform(value: string, args: string, terms: string): any {
```

And pass it via the template, like so:

```
<read-more [text]="course?.keywords | highlight : searchText : searchTerms" [maxLength]="50"> </read-more>
```

This allows us to pass both `searchText` and the extra value

Here, I have created an extra parameter called `test`, and I'm passing in the `searchTerms`